# Troubleshooting Synchronization Issue in a Multi-threaded C Program for Supermarket Simulation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I'm working on a multi-threaded C program that simulates a supermarket with restocking and potentially customer behaviors (currently commented out). The program involves several threads representing managers, employees, and stock checking. I'm facing an issue where the restocking logic results in incorrect shelf amounts - some products are overstocked, and some don't reach the expected levels after restocking.

Here's a simplified overview of the program's structure:

```
Manager Thread (manager_behavior): Checks if products need restocking and initiates the restocking process.
Employee Thread (employee_behavior): Performs the actual restocking of products.
Stock Checker Thread (check_stock_levels): Monitors stock levels and signals for restocking if necessary.
```

I've ensured synchronization using mutexes, semaphores, and condition variables. However, the issue seems to be with either the synchronization or the logic in updating shelf_amount.

```
void* manager_behavior(void* arg) {
    ShelvingTeam *team = (ShelvingTeam *)arg;
    Supermarket *market = team->market;

    while (market->is_simulation_active) {
        for (int i = 0; i < market->num_products; i++) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&market->products[i].restock_mutex);

            // Check if the product needs restocking and if it's not already being restocked
            if (market->products[i].shelf_amount < market->products[i].restock_threshold && !market->products[i].is_being_restocked) {
                market->products[i].is_being_restocked = 1;
                // Unlock immediately after setting the flag to allow other threads to see the updated status
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->products[i].restock_mutex);

                int total_restock_amount = market->products[i].restock_threshold - market->products[i].shelf_amount;
                int base_restock_amount = total_restock_amount / team->num_employees;
                int remaining_amount = total_restock_amount % team->num_employees;

                // Safely deduct the amount from storage
               // pthread_mutex_lock(&market->storage_mutex);  // Assuming there is a storage_mutex for thread-safe storage access
                market->products[i].storage_amount -= total_restock_amount;
                //pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->storage_mutex);

                // Update team's task details
                update_team_task_details(team, market->products[i].id, base_restock_amount, remaining_amount);

                // Wait for all employees to complete the task
                wait_for_employees(team);

                // Reset the product's status and notify the team
                reset_product_status(market, i, team);
            } else {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->products[i].restock_mutex);
            }
        }
        sleep(1); // Control the loop frequency
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Helper functions for better modularity and readability
void update_team_task_details(ShelvingTeam *team, int product_id, int base_amount, int remaining_amount) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);
    team->current_product_id = product_id;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->restock_amount_mutex);
    team->restock_amount = base_amount;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->restock_amount_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->remaining_amount_mutex);
    team->remaining_amount = remaining_amount;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->remaining_amount_mutex);

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&team->condition_var);
}

void wait_for_employees(ShelvingTeam *team) {
    for (int j = 0; j < team->num_employees; j++) {
        sem_wait(&team->restock_semaphore);
    }
}

void reset_product_status(Supermarket *market, int productIndex, ShelvingTeam *team) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&market->products[productIndex].restock_mutex);
    market->products[productIndex].is_being_restocked = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->products[productIndex].restock_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->employees_finished_mutex);
    team->employees_finished = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->employees_finished_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);
    team->current_product_id = 0;
    printf("Product %d new shelf amount is %d\n", productIndex + 1, market->products[productIndex].shelf_amount);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);
}



void* employee_behavior(void* arg) {
    ShelvingTeam *team = (ShelvingTeam *)arg;
    Supermarket *market = team->market;

    while (market->is_simulation_active) {
        // Wait for a restocking task
        wait_for_task(team);

        // Retrieve the task details
        int product_id, employee_restock_amount;
        get_task_details(team, &product_id, &employee_restock_amount);

        // Perform the restocking
        restock_product(market, product_id, employee_restock_amount);

        // Notify completion of the task
        notify_task_completion(team);
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Helper functions
void wait_for_task(ShelvingTeam *team) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->shelving_mutex);
    while (team->current_product_id == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&team->condition_var, &team->shelving_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->shelving_mutex);
}

void get_task_details(ShelvingTeam *team, int *product_id, int *restock_amount) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);
    *product_id = team->current_product_id;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->restock_amount_mutex);
    *restock_amount = team->restock_amount;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->restock_amount_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->remaining_amount_mutex);
    if (team->remaining_amount > 0) {
        (*restock_amount)++;
        team->remaining_amount--;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->remaining_amount_mutex);
}

void restock_product(Supermarket *market, int product_id, int amount) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&market->products[product_id - 1].restock_mutex);
    market->products[product_id - 1].shelf_amount += amount;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->products[product_id - 1].restock_mutex);
}

void notify_task_completion(ShelvingTeam *team) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->shelving_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->employees_finished_mutex);
    team->employees_finished++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->employees_finished_mutex);
    sem_post(&team->restock_semaphore);
    
    if (team->employees_finished == team->num_employees) {
        reset_current_product_id(team);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->shelving_mutex);
}

void reset_current_product_id(ShelvingTeam *team) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);
    team->current_product_id = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&team->current_product_id_mutex);
}










void check_stock_levels(Supermarket* market) {
    while (market->is_simulation_active) {
        for (int i = 0; i < market->num_products; i++) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&market->products[i].restock_mutex);

            // Check if the product needs restocking and if it's not currently being restocked
            if (market->products[i].shelf_amount < market->products[i].restock_threshold && !market->products[i].is_being_restocked) {
                

                int team_id = select_team_for_restocking(market);  // Helper function to select a team based on some criteria
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->products[i].restock_mutex);

                // Signal the selected team to start restocking
                signal_team_to_restock(&market->shelving_teams[team_id]);
            } else {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&market->products[i].restock_mutex);
            }
        }
        sleep(1); // Control check frequency
    }
}

// Helper functions
int select_team_for_restocking(Supermarket *market) {
    ret
urn rand() % market->num_shelving_teams;
}

void signal_team_to_restock(ShelvingTeam *team) {
    pthread_cond_signal(&team->condition_var);
}
```

this is the struct

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

// Forward declaration of Supermarket structure
struct Supermarket;

// Product structure
typedef struct {
    int id;                 // Unique product ID
    int shelf_amount;       // Amount of product on the shelf
    int storage_amount;     // Amount of product in storage
    int restock_threshold;  // Threshold for restocking
    int is_being_restocked; // Flag to indicate if the product is being restocked
    pthread_mutex_t restock_mutex; // Mutex for restocking
} Product;

typedef struct {
    int team_id;
    int num_employees;
    pthread_t *employees;  // Array of employee thread IDs
    int employees_finished;
    struct Supermarket *market;
    pthread_mutex_t shelving_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition_var;
    sem_t restock_semaphore;
    int current_product_id;
    int restock_amount;
    int remaining_amount;
    pthread_mutex_t current_product_id_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_t restock_amount_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_t remaining_amount_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_t employees_finished_mutex;
    int *completion_status;  // Array to track completion status of each employee
} ShelvingTeam;


// Supermarket structure
typedef struct Supermarket {
    Product *products;                // Array of products
    int num_products;                 // Number of products
    ShelvingTeam *shelving_teams;     // Array of shelving teams
    int num_shelving_teams;           // Number of shelving teams
    int simulation_time_limit;        // Time limit for the simulation in minutes
    int customer_arrival_min;         // Minimum customer arrival time
    int customer_arrival_max;         // Maximum customer arrival time
    int is_simulation_active;         // Flag to indicate if the simulation is active
    int products_shm_id; 
    pthread_mutex_t team_selection_mutex; // Mutex for team selection synchronization
} Supermarket;

// Customer structure
typedef struct {
    int customer_id;                  // Unique customer ID
    int *selected_items;              // Array of selected item IDs
    int *selected_quantities;         // Array of quantities for each selected item
    Supermarket *market;              // Pointer to the supermarket
} Customer;

#endif  // STRUCTS_H
```

this is the main

```
#include "structs.h"
#include "config.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "behaviors.h"
#include <semaphore.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Starting the supermarket simulation...\n");

    Config config;
    if (read_config("config.txt", &config) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read config file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Configuration loaded successfully.\n");

    Supermarket supermarket;
    supermarket.num_products = config.num_products;
    supermarket.num_shelving_teams = config.num_shelving_teams;
    supermarket.simulation_time_limit = config.simulation_time_limit;
    supermarket.is_simulation_active = 1;

    int shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Product) * supermarket.num_products, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shm_id < 0) {
        perror("shmget failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    supermarket.products = (Product *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (supermarket.products == (void *)-1) {
        perror("shmat failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_products; i++) {
        supermarket.products[i].id = i + 1;
        supermarket.products[i].shelf_amount = config.shelf_amounts[i];
        supermarket.products[i].storage_amount = config.storage_amounts[i];
        supermarket.products[i].restock_threshold = config.restocking_thresholds[i];
        supermarket.products[i].is_being_restocked = 0;
        pthread_mutex_init(&supermarket.products[i].restock_mutex, NULL);
    }

    int sem_shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) * supermarket.num_shelving_teams, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (sem_shm_id < 0) {
        perror("shmget failed for semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sem_t* semaphores = (sem_t*)shmat(sem_shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (semaphores == (void *)-1) {
        perror("shmat failed for semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    supermarket.shelving_teams = malloc(sizeof(ShelvingTeam) * supermarket.num_shelving_teams);
    for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_shelving_teams; i++) {
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].team_id = i + 1;
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].current_product_id = 0;
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].restock_amount = 0;
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].remaining_amount = 0;
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].num_employees = config.employees_per_team[i];
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * supermarket.shelving_teams[i].num_employees);
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees_finished = 0;
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].market = &supermarket;
        pthread_mutex_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].shelving_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].current_product_id_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].restock_amount_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].remaining_amount_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees_finished_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].condition_var, NULL);
        sem_init(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].restock_semaphore, 0, 0);
        supermarket.shelving_teams[i].completion_status = malloc(sizeof(int) * supermarket.shelving_teams[i].num_employees);
        for (int j = 0; j < supermarket.shelving_teams[i].num_employees; j++) {
            supermarket.shelving_teams[i].completion_status[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    pthread_t manager_threads[supermarket.num_shelving_teams];
    for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_shelving_teams; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&manager_threads[i], NULL, manager_behavior, &supermarket.shelving_teams[i]) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create manager thread");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < supermarket.shelving_teams[i].num_employees; j++) {
            if (pthread_create(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees[j], NULL, employee_behavior, &supermarket.shelving_teams[i]) != 0) {
                perror("Failed to create employee thread");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_t stock_thread;
    if (pthread_create(&stock_thread, NULL, (void *(*)(void *))check_stock_levels, &supermarket) != 0) {
        perror("Failed to create stock checker thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_shelving_teams; i++) {
        pthread_join(manager_threads[i], NULL);
        for (int j = 0; j < supermarket.shelving_teams[i].num_employees; j++) {
            pthread_join(supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees[j], NULL);
        }
    }
    pthread_join(stock_thread, NULL);

    shmdt(supermarket.products);
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_shelving_teams; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].shelving_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].current_product_id_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].restock_amount_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].remaining_amount_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees_finished_mutex);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].condition_var);
        sem_destroy(&semaphores[i]);
        free(supermarket.shelving_teams[i].employees);
        free(supermarket.shelving_teams[i].completion_status);
    }

    free(supermarket.shelving_teams);
    shmdt(semaphores);
    shmctl(sem_shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    printf("Supermarket simulation ended.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Issue:

Some products are being overstocked (e.g., Product 5 goes to 23 instead of a maximum of 20), and some products seem to be restocked multiple times in quick succession (e.g., Product 8).

I suspect the issue might be in the synchronization or the logic of updating shelf_amount. I'm looking for insights into what might be causing these anomalies and how to resolve them.

this is from the output:

```
Starting the supermarket simulation...
Configuration loaded successfully.
Product 1 new shelf amount is 10
Product 2 new shelf amount is 15
Product 3 new shelf amount is 12
Product 4 new shelf amount is 8
Product 5 new shelf amount is 23
Product 7 new shelf amount is 10
Product 8 new shelf amount is 19
Product 6 new shelf amount is 18
Product 9 new shelf amount is 19
Product 8 new shelf amount is 22
Product 10 new shelf amount is 8
Product 10 new shelf amount is 9
```

Comment: almost the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773968/protecting-each-index-of-shared-memory-arry-with-a-semaphore

Comment: _Side note:_ You have many instances of (e.g.) `for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_shelving_teams; i++) { pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].shelving_mutex); pthread_mutex_destroy(&supermarket.shelving_teams[i].current_product_id_mutex); }` Thus, you're repeating the verbose `supermarket.shelving_teams[i]` a _lot_. This can be simplified with an extra pointer: `for (int i = 0; i < supermarket.num_shelving_teams; i++) { ShelvingTeam *team = &supermarket.shelving_teams[i]; pthread_mutex_destroy(&team->shelving_mutex); pthread_mutex_destroy(&team->current_product_id_mutex); }`

Comment: The above is true for many `for` loops for many different structs. Fixing that can improve readability a lot.

Comment: You've included _most_ of your code, but not all. We would really like an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].